# `npm install` fails at `git submodule update`

Tags: react-native, npm

I have a react-native app with a few dependencies hosted on AWS CodeCommit.

I've been working on this project for a while but after recent upgrade of node & npm I'm unable to run the app. It gets stuck at `npm install`. Here's the error -

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: git submodule update -q --init --recursive
npm ERR! warning: templates not found in C:\Users\myComputer\AppData\Local\Temp\pacote-git-template-tmp\git-clone-c78347e9
npm ERR! warning: unable to access 'Examples/SDWebImage TV Demo/Assets.xcassets/App Icon & Top Shelf Image.brandassets/App Icon - Large.imagestack/Back.imagestacklayer/Content.imageset/.gitattributes': Filename too long
npm ERR! warning: unable to access 'Examples/SDWebImage TV Demo/Assets.xcassets/App Icon & Top Shelf Image.brandassets/App Icon - Large.imagestack/Front.imagestacklayer/Content.imageset/.gitattributes': Filename too long
npm ERR! error: unable to create file Examples/SDWebImage TV Demo/Assets.xcassets/App Icon & Top Shelf Image.brandassets/App Icon - Large.imagestack/Front.imagestacklayer/Content.imageset/Contents.json: Filename too long
npm ERR! warning: unable to access 'Examples/SDWebImage TV Demo/Assets.xcassets/App Icon & Top Shelf Image.brandassets/App Icon - Large.imagestack/Middle.imagestacklayer/Content.imageset/.gitattributes': Filename too long
npm ERR! error: unable to create file Examples/SDWebImage TV Demo/Assets.xcassets/App Icon & Top Shelf Image.brandassets/App Icon - Large.imagestack/Middle.imagestacklayer/Content.imageset/Contents.json: Filename too long
npm ERR! warning: unable to access 'Examples/SDWebImage TV Demo/Assets.xcassets/App Icon & Top Shelf Image.brandassets/App Icon - Small.imagestack/Back.imagestacklayer/Content.imageset/.gitattributes': Filename too long
npm ERR! warning: unable to access 'Examples/SDWebImage TV Demo/Assets.xcassets/App Icon & Top Shelf Image.brandassets/App Icon - Small.imagestack/Front.imagestacklayer/Content.imageset/.gitattributes': Filename too long
npm ERR! error: unable to create file Examples/SDWebImage TV Demo/Assets.xcassets/App Icon & Top Shelf Image.brandassets/App Icon - Small.imagestack/Front.imagestacklayer/Content.imageset/Contents.json: Filename too long
npm ERR! warning: unable to access 'Examples/SDWebImage TV Demo/Assets.xcassets/App Icon & Top Shelf Image.brandassets/App Icon - Small.imagestack/Middle.imagestacklayer/Content.imageset/.gitattributes': Filename too long
npm ERR! error: unable to create file Examples/SDWebImage TV Demo/Assets.xcassets/App Icon & Top Shelf Image.brandassets/App Icon - Small.imagestack/Middle.imagestacklayer/Content.imageset/Contents.json: Filename too long
npm ERR! Unable to checkout 'dc5c974b89509992d6c6e0d0510344fd0e35baa6' in submodule path 'ios/Vendor/SDWebImage'
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myComputer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-18T15_22_41_579Z-debug.log
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/kukiron/2ceaa499cf3c327790a49055d6110f3b)'s a link to the complete log file.

As you can see I'm working on a Windows machine. When I try to build the app on MacOS, it works perfectly fine.
I have tried different versions of Node, NPM & Git but the error persists.

I'm suspecting this is a Windows related issue but no idea how to fix this.

Comment: have you tried to clean cache ? `npm cache clean --force` remove `node_modules` folder and reinstal all packages?

Comment: @Maielo did try `npm cache clean --force` too. Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I found the problem & a workaround.

The problem was that we were using our forked version of `react-native-fast-image` & that caused the error when doing `npm-install`. I cloned our fork of the repo & linked it in the `package.json` as -

```
"react-native-fast-image": "file:../react-native-fast-image",
```

instead of -

```
"react-native-fast-image": "git+https://github.com/{account-name}/react-native-fast-image.git",
```

Which solved the issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fool proof way to do this unless npm itself fixes it by respecting `.npmignores` file.
I have tried the @garfiere solution which works fine.

**Alternate Solution:**

I recently tried another solution for this that does not require cloning package manually from some other local folder.

Instead I deleted `.gitmodules` file from my package that had submodules.
This fixed the `npm install`.
Then added a shell script in `postinstall` to create `.gitmodules` file back.
Also added .gitmodules in .gitignore so its not pushed again.

**Problem details**

This happens when following scenarios take place

- You have a package in package.json that is a git repo.
- This package contains a submodule that you don't have access to.

Even if you add `.gitmodules` in `.npmignore`. It still won't work. As this all happens in npm cache folder where everything is fetched.
@garfiere solution targets 1st point. My solution targets 2nd one.